# Setting selected value on dynamically generated rows with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a HTML grid which is being generated dynamically with row ID's of [row_X]. How can I use jQuery to iterate each row, locate child select controls and set the "selected" value?

```html
<tr id="row_0">
  <td>
    <select class="selection">
         <option id='1' value='1'>A</option>
         <option id='2' value='2'>B</option>
         <option id='3' value='3'>C</option>
         <option id='4' value='4'>D</option>
         <option id='5' value='5'>E</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr id="row_1">
  <td>
    <select class="selection">
         <option id='1' value='1'>A</option>
         <option id='2' value='2'>B</option>
         <option id='3' value='3'>C</option>
         <option id='4' value='4'>D</option>
         <option id='5' value='5'>E</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Regarding your option elements, ID is supposed to be unique. Why do you want IDs in option elements anyway? You can set the current selection by setting the .value property of the select element.

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#row_0").find( "select" ).val(1);
```

Refer to [jQuery documentation for .val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)

Answer (score 0):

Try changing `id` to `class` at `option` elements ; selector `$("table tbody tr .selection")` to select `select` elements ; utilize `.each()` to iterate `select` elements , use `options.selectedIndex` of `select` element with `index` of `option` to set selected `option`; e.g.; to select `option` having value `"B"` , set `selectedIndex` to `1`

```js
$(function() {
  $("table tbody tr .selection").each(function(index, el) {
    el.options.selectedIndex = 1
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row_0">
      <td>
        <select class="selection">
          <option class='1' value='1'>A</option>
          <option class='2' value='2'>B</option>
          <option class='3' value='3'>C</option>
          <option class='4' value='4'>D</option>
          <option class='5' value='5'>E</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row_1">
      <td>
        <select class="selection">
          <option class='1' value='1'>A</option>
          <option class='2' value='2'>B</option>
          <option class='3' value='3'>C</option>
          <option class='4' value='4'>D</option>
          <option class='5' value='5'>E</option>
        </select>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```